# Windows 10 File Explorer crashes

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10

Suddenly my file explorer has been giving me problem. Whenever I click on it, It does not open at once. But takes around 2 minutes to open . And even after opening, it just keeps saying 'Working on it'. I just could not open any directory. And the desktop just kept crashing. Finally I managed to open 'Event Viewer' from Run and found the event which causes this. It is this :

```
The Microsoft Account Sign-in Assistant service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

I then opened services.msc and disabled the Service. Now everything seems to be working fine. Now I want to get rid of this problem forever. How can I do this ?

These are some other services which also showed up in the Event Viewer in crash state :

```
DCOM got error "1053" attempting to start the service UsoSvc with arguments "Unavailable" in order to run the server:
{B91D5831-B1BD-4608-8198-D72E155020F7}
```

And this:

```
The Update Orchestrator Service service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Comment: I've added my own answer on how to get rid of this since this question became popular. I've also accepted it so that people will know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the problem by disabling both **Microsoft Sign in** and **UsoSvc** services.

The **UsoSvc** is a service which is used by organizations to install software without having the user login to do it. I did not need it so I disabled it.

Since then my file explorer is really fast and it never crashed again.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue after upgrading, It had to do with context menu add-on that I had. I used [ccleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to disable the add-on to verify that was the problem and eventually remove it. There is also [autoruns from sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) that could help you achieve the same result.

Comment: I had to run Autoruns, and then I disabled just about everything under the "Shell" or "Explorer" filter (context menus, icon overlays, icon handlers, etc) to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you're using all the latest Windows 10 drivers for your machine.
If problem persists, create/use an(other) Administrative account to verify the present profile isn't corrupted. Use the same Microsoft Account sign-in credentials with the alternative account or try creating and using a local account instead. If all else fails, try repairing/reinstalling Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I opened file explorer by going back through the directory chain from Control Panel. Then searched for `explorer.exe` and made a short cut on DESKTOP.
Explorer ran successfully from this shortcut and thereafter the icon in the task bar worked as well. An unexpected fix

Answer (score 0):

I went to Control Panel, searched/opened File Explorer and opened File Explorer Options.
At the top of window, I changed Open File Explorer to: This PC (from quick access.)
Now file explorer works fine.