# Windows 10 explorer.exe crashes

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I just upgraded my laptop from Windows 7 to Windows 10. After logging in explorer.exe crashes after about a minute and the screen goes blank except for the cursor. However, I can get to the task manager. I have tried going to the task manager and manually running explorer.exe but it immediately stops.

I have tried starting in safe mode, disabling services and disabling programs from startup but nothing works. There are similar question out there but none seem to work.

It's a Dell laptop, unfortunately I don't remember the rest of the specs. I think it's a core i7 with 8gb ram.

Comment: Try creating a new user. It sounds like your user profile is corrupted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 File Explorer crashes](http://superuser.com/questions/954869/windows-10-file-explorer-crashes)

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to add and the desktop goes black except for the cursor. I can't do much in windows except get to the task manager. Starting from "Run" is there a way I can launch user management? I can try disabling Microsoft Sign in and UsoSvc services from the task manager.

Comment: @DavidPostill I could not create a new user. I got an error with a big red circle, "Class not registered".

Answer (score 1):

The solution ended up being to backup the computer and do a clean install.