# Windows 10 File Explorer Windows keep disappearing

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Everyone in our firm of about 40 people are experiencing Windows 10 File Explorer windows disappearing.  Poof.  They use them for a random amount of time and then when they look for it, it has disappeared.  The amount of time it stays open is random.  This is extremely irritating to my users.

I've tried making each Explorer window a separate process and even did a repair on Windows Explorer components itself.  Nothings works.

Is this happening to anyone else?

Comment: "Is this happening to anyone else?" - No;  Which means it's something unique about the installation image used by your firm.  You have not provided us enough information to even guide down the path that would result in you identifying the conflicting piece of software installed on your system.  My best advice is start with a clean image and one by one install the applications until the behavior surfaces..

Comment: [Windows 10 File Explorer crashes](https://superuser.com/questions/954869/windows-10-file-explorer-crashes?rq=1)

Comment: What is in the event logs?

Comment: I assume that the explorer.exe process is crashing due to a common third party library.  I would suggest: 1. Create a directory "C:\dumps\", download procdump https://docs.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/procdump and in an admin prompt run: `procdump -ma -i c:\dumps`.  Next time it crashes, you should have a dump file.  Maybe you can zip and share it.

Comment: is explorer crashing? look in eventlog. if you see app crash information, follow [this topic to create and analyze a crash dump](https://superuser.com/a/1233294/174557)

Answer (score 1):

We found this to be related to Drive Mappings in Group policy.  We change the mapped drives from "Replace" to "Update"

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Congrats on finding the core issue. Could you improve your answer by providing step-by-step instructions on making that change?